# Only show inputs if selected in settings page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, mern

I am trying to figure out how to have a user go to `/settings` and pick a few check boxes then when they go to `/new` they will only see the inputs that correspond to the ones they selected when in `/settings`.

I am not sure how I would do this, I know I need to save it to the database but how should I be pulling the data to have only the inputs show I want. I am thinking of setting the options as boolean's and when it is true (checked off) then it would show the input. My only issue with this idea is that I am unsure how to do this with as few database queries as possible. I ideally would only send 1 query instead of say 10 or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `users` collection, add `settings` field.

Example `user` document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c20694d58a3e3e393fe779"),
    "email" : "user@gmail.com",
    "role" : "user",
    "password" : "$2a$10$5TK8N8T1VohE6hHklqdeCubYmOimBaAcnHWHSKxb4x6AudlWeDeEa",
    "created" : ISODate("2017-09-20T06:11:32.014Z"),
    "settings": {
        "option_1": true,
        "option_2": false,
        "option_3": true,
        "option_4": true
    }
}
```

Then, upon loading the `/new` route, read the `user.settings` and in your templating engine, display content basing on the settings.

If mentioned settings are to be used on more than one route (`/new`), consider storing them in session.

Additionally, if you use a framework like angular, consider adding the settings to the global service.

Comment: I am using the MERN stack but an not familiar with React, does it have global service like features I could use? As for the collection, would adding in an extra layer to what you put be an issue, like: `settings -> IT-> option 1` then have say `settings -> auto-> option 1`

Comment: Don't bother with using global service right now, you will notice it's necessity upon needing it _for real_; it was just an offtopic tip. I am not familiar with MERN nor React, so cannot really help you here.

Adding an extra layer would not be an issue at all, you can nest it as much as you like.

Comment: Thank you, I have marked your answer as the solution.